# How to generate multiple random numbers in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Im looking for a function that will randomly generate 15 numbers. Is there anything part of the apple framework that can do this?

Comment: `arc4random()`? What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can use to get random number `arc4random_uniform(upper bound)` with upper bound here would be your required number...

```
arc4random_uniform(15)
```

or

```
int r = arc4random() % 15;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, could you share an example of how this would work within view did load?

Comment: call **int r = arc4random_uniform(15);** inside the viewDidLoad method and u will get non-repeating random number between 15...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
arc4random() % 15;
```

this will generate 15 random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create helper method do generate as many random numbers as parameter you pass to it 
and returns array of numbers:

```
-(NSArray*)generateRandomNumbers:(NSUInteger)count {

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        [array addObject:@(arc4random())];
    }

    return array;
}
```